# How much extra distance to an event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, curvature, event-horizon

How much extra distance would I have to travel through space to get from Earth to a stellar mass event horizon?
(compared to the same point in space without a black hole)

Comment: Wouldn't the point in space be the same in both cases, regardless of the existence of the black hole?

Comment: I don't think so, there is curvature outside th EH. The smaller the BH the greater the curvature at the EH?

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you're not asking the question you're really interested in, because the answer to your question is really boring. If you jump into a black hole you'll see the event horizon retreating before you, and you'll never cross it. The distance you've travelled is an ambiguous quantity since of course in your frame you're stationary and have travelled no distance at all. The time you take to pass the distance $r=r_s$ then hit the singularity is finite, and for stellar mass black holes very short.

A far more interesting question is if you hover outside the horizon and let down a tape measure how long would it have to be to reach the horizon i.e. what do you get by integrating $dr$ in a radial direction towards the event horizon? The Schwarzschild metric is:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)} + r^2 d\Omega^2 $$

Lets suppose we hover at a distance $r_1$ from the singularity and let down a tape measure to measure the distance to some point at a radial distance of $r_2$. Because $dt$ and $d\Omega$ are constant the equation for the line element simplifies to:

$$ ds = \frac{dr}{\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{1/2}} $$

To get the length of the tape we just need to integrate this expression from $r_1$ to $r_2$:

$$\begin{align}
 s &= \int_{r_2}^{r_1} \frac{dr}{\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{1/2}} \\
   &= \int_{r_2}^{r_1} \frac{r^{1/2}dr}{\left(r-r_s\right)^{1/2}}
\end{align}$$

To integrate this we cheat and look up the answer in [a GR book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Exploring-Black-Holes-Introduction-Relativity/dp/020138423X), the result being:

$$ s = \left[ z \sqrt{z ^2 - r_s} + r_s \ln \left( z + \sqrt{z ^2 - r_s} \right) \right]_{z_2}^{z_1} $$

where we've used the substitution $r = z^2$ to make the integral manageable.

To make this concrete lets take a black hole with the mass of the Sun, so $r_s$ = 2954m, and we'll start from 5km out i.e. $r_1 = 5000$. Let's graph the length of the tape as a function of $r_2$:

[image: Length of tape]

The magenta line is the Newtonian result, i.e. if space was flat, and the blue line is what we actually measure. The tape measure distance from $r = 5km to the event horizon is about 4,780m compared to the Newtonian calculation of 2046m.

So the affect of the curvature is to make the distance measured radially greater than $r_1 - r_2$. However I must emphasise that this is not what you'd measure if I threw you into the black hole. This is the distance measured by an observer hovering far from the event horizon.

Comment: That was the question I was thinking of. You missed my edits. How far out from the EH does the curvature extend, to earth.

Comment: @Jitter: no, you're asking about **travelling** to the event horizon and that's completely different from hovering outside it. The former is a rainfall frame and the latter is a shell frame. They measure completely different distances.

Comment: I did not read/think very clearly did I. My question still stands. Is there anything I should know about measuring by traveling from Earth over measuring from orbit?

Comment: @Jitter: have a look at my answer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83127/watching-something-fall-into-a-black-hole-from-far-away and see if that is relevant to your question. If you so might want to edit your question or maybe ask a new one.

Comment: Ok, I check the link and see if my answer will be more or less than a light year;-)

Comment: I can't find my answer there so I'll wait for someone who can calculate the distance.

Comment: @Jitter: OK, OK, I've done the calculation :-)

Comment: Thankyou for that graph I still need a graph to show me the difference between smaller and larger black holes and maybe where the vent horizon is located compared to the sigularity etc.

Comment: If the tape-measure-dropping distance to the event horizon is infinite, I wonder what a falling observer right next to the tape measure would see?  Since they hit the horizon in a finite proper time, it would seem they'd have to see an infinite length of tape fly by in a finite time.

Comment: @NathanReed: The tape measure distance isn't infinite. I did say it was, didn't I, but the equation for the tape measure distance clearly doesn't go to infinity as $r \rightarrow r_s$. I need to go back and correct that,

Comment: @JohnRennie I have a followup question.  Let's say your helper lowers his tape measurer to the singularity.  When he is done, you climb down the tape measurer.  You are immortal and have infinite strength, etc.  What is your experience as you descend, firmly anchored to this thing measuring your arm-stride/speed as much as it is measuring the distance to the singularity?

Comment: @Daniel You cannot  anchor anything inside the event horizon. Not even hypothetically.

Comment: @RobJeffries If It takes extra tape to make it to the event horizon, lowering yourself down the tape should take extra, measurable, strides with your arm.  So how could it feel like an ordinary distance?  Singularity vs event horizon is not really the point.

Comment: *If you jump into a black hole you'll see the event horizon retreating before you, and you'll never cross it.* Not true. An infalling observer crosses the horizon in finite proper time, and also hits the singularity after a finite proper time. You're getting mixed up with the Doppler-shifted observations of a distant observer.

Comment: The example of the tape measure is also misleading physically. The tensile strength of the tape measure is limited by the dominant energy condition, and  any tape measure that obeys this constraint will break before reaching the horizon, if a static observer keeps the upper end taut.

Comment: @BenCrowell what I said is correct. As an infalling observer you will observe an apparent horizon that retreats before you. That is, there is a surface beyond which light emitted radially cannot reach you, but this surface retreats before you as you fall inwards.  I agree that you pass the distance $r=2M$ in  finite time, and indeed that is exactly what I said in the last sentence of my first paragraph.

Comment: If you take this equation for ds, then multiply by the time dilation factor and 2/c, will the integral give you the expected round trip time for light going into then climbing out of a gravitational well?

Answer (score 2):

The integral John Rennie gave can be upgraded by the gammafactor, assuming the motion of the observer is in the $\rm r$ direction, and the large $\rm R$ is the observer dependend physical distance:

$${\rm \Delta R= \int_{r_2}^{r_1}}=\frac{\sqrt{g_{\rm r r}}}{\gamma} \ \rm dr$$

but you have to check what gammafactor to use for which coordinates. If you are falling into the black hole from rest at infinity or with the negative escape velocity

$$\rm v=-v_{esc}=-c \sqrt{r_s/r}$$

in the classical [Schwarzschild/Droste](http://yukterez.rf.gd/f/einstein.equations/files/06.html) coordinates we have

$$ \sqrt{g_{\rm r r}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rm r_s/r}}$$

and the gammafactor for the infalling observer also is

$$ \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rm v^2/c^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rm r_s/r}} $$

so the radial expansion and the length contraction cancel out in his frame:

$$ \frac{\sqrt{g_{\rm r r}}}{\gamma} = 1$$

that is why in [Gullstrand/Painlevé](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/08.html) coordinates where the $\rm -v_{esc}$ is absorbed into the $g_{\rm t r}$ and the local velocity $\rm v$ is not relative to stationary but free falling reference observers (the so called raindrops), and $\rm v=0$ in that coordinates equals $\rm v=-v_{esc}$ in the other coordinates, you get

$$ \sqrt{\bar g_{\rm r r}} = 1$$

and the [spatial components](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/714087/24093) of the covariant metric are euclidean, so

> [Hamilton & Lisle](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060) wrote: *"In the river model, space itself flows like a river through a flat background"*

and the distance is simply $\rm r_2-r_1$. If you are not falling with the escape velocity, the local factor doesn't cancel to $1$ and the distance is different from $\rm r_2-r_1$. If you are slower than the escape velocity it is larger, and if you are faster it is smaller.

Behind the horizon it is the other way around if you take $\rm v$ (relative to the black hole itself) as a measure for how fast you are, but note that $\rm v$ and $\rm dr/d\tau$ are generally different things. The closer to $\rm c$ your $\rm v$ is (from above or below), the more contraction you get. Inside the black hole where you have to have $\rm v>c$, a smaller $\rm v$ (but still larger than $\rm c$) equals larger $\rm dr/d\tau$ than a $\rm v$ much larger than $\rm c$ and $\rm dr/d\tau \to \infty$ equals $\rm v \to c$ outside and inside of the horizon.

In special relativity (where the escape velocity is always $0$ since there's no gravity) the distance for a moving observer would also be shorter than $\rm r_2-r_1$, since when you start moving towards your target, the distance shrinks by the gammafactor of your velocity.