# How to understand the total proper mass?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, mass, neutron-stars

In Wald's General Relativity, page 126, he difined a function $m(r)$ as
$$
m(r)=4\pi\int^r_0\rho(r')r'^2dr',
$$
where $\rho(r)$ is just the $\rho$ appeared in a perfect fluid stress-energy tensor.
From this, he indicated that the total mass in Newtonian gravity as $M=m(R)$. He also defined the total proper mass, which is
$$
M_p=\int^R_0\rho(r)r^2\sqrt{^{(3)}\textrm{g}}\quad d^3x=4\pi\int^R_0\rho(r)r^2\big[1-\frac{2m(r)}{r}\big]^{-1/2}dr.
$$
Then he gave the gravitational binding energy $E_B$ as the difference between $M$ and $M_p$:
$$
E_B=M_p-M.
$$
I am having a difficulty in recognizing the physical meaning of these three quantities. Is the "proper" here the same meaning as the proper time? Could someone give an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

The "proper volume" of a spherical shell is
$$dV = 4\pi r^2\,\left(1 - \frac{2m(r)}{r}\right)^{-1/2}dr\ ,$$
where $m(r)$ is the mass that a distant observer would say is responsible for the gravitational effect exterior to $r$ and $G=c=1$. This expression takes account of the fact that the proper distance between $r_2$ and $r_1$ is *not* $r_2-r_1$.

Whilst the surface area of a sphere is $4\pi r^2$ for the Schwarzschild metric (outside a spherically symmetric mass, e.g., see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/193066/43351)), the proper distance between two points separated on a radial line (i.e. $ds$ when $dt=d\theta=d\phi=0$) is
$$ ds = \left(1 - \frac{2m(r)}{r}\right)^{-1/2}dr\ .$$
Hence the expression for "proper volume". The proper mass is just the proper volume multiplied by the density.

$M(R)$ is the *observable* mass/energy of the star - the mass that you would deduce for example by studying the motion of a binary companion.

However, $M_p$, the total proper mass/energy is the mass that the consituents of the star would have if they were dispersed to infinity by giving them exactly the gravitational binding energy.

The binding energy is a negative energy term and the gravitational effects of the mass of the star are reduced by the binding energy. i.e. $M < M_p$. I therefore assume that Wald is defining $E_B$ as a positive quantity?

Comment: Yes, E_B is positive in Wald's book. Your answer helps a lot. Thx!