# Regarding 'The Science of Interstellar', space warping section

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, curvature

While reading Thorne's 'The Science of Interstellar', I came across this piece of information:

> 'Now, the Sun’s equatorial plane divides space into two identical halves, that above the plane and that below. Nonetheless, Figure 4.4 shows the equatorial plane as warped like the surface of a bowl. It bends downward inside and near the Sun, so that diameters of circles around the Sun, when multiplied by π (3.14159 . . . ), are larger than circumferences—larger, in the case of the Sun, by roughly 100 kilometers.'

Has anyone that has read this book got an explanation for me, I do not get the d*pi compared to circumference part, why does it differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circumference of a circle is only $\pi$ times its diameter in flat space.

The space around and inside the Sun is curved by its mass-energy. As a result, the proper distance between two radial points is larger than the difference in their radial coordinates. However, the circumference (a path of constant radial coordinate) is still $2\pi$ times that radial coordinate.

The way to imagine this is a circle drawn on the curved surface of a sphere. The radius you would (hypothetically) measure is the length of the path along the curved surface to the centre. However, the circumference is $\pi$ times the diameter of the circle projected onto a flat surface, so is less than $2\pi$ times the radius you previously measured.

[image: Curved space]

See also [How much extra distance to an event horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/85975/how-much-extra-distance-to-an-event-horizon), though the maths for calculating the proper radius for an object with a density profile (like the Sun) is more complicated than for a black hole.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read the [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_coordinates#A_family_of_static_nested_spheres) about.

> However, note well: in general, the Schwarzschild radial coordinate
>   does not accurately represent radial distances, i.e. distances taken
>   along the spacelike geodesic congruence which arise as the integral
>   curves of $\partial_r$.

Comment: To be frank, this complicates things... I would expect it to not be this difficult since Thorne goes into great detail in this book about a lot he claims. With this, he does not say anything so it must be a small detail I missed.

Comment: Maybe the wikipedia article is not the best, but every book in general relativity could be good. The problem is that the coordinates you’re using when you search a spherically symmetric static solution to Einstein equation (that is schwarschild one) couldn’t retain the feature that the circumference is long 2pi*r if the space isn’t flat, because this is a property of euclidean space, but a curved (static) 3-space is not euclidean at all.