# acceleration and time dilation

Tags: acceleration

Is it true that a freely-falling body accelerates because, as time slows toward the center of the earth, each second is longer than the preceding one, giving the body further to travel? A simple yes or no will do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you want an answer beyond a simple yes or no have a look at my answer to [How does "curved space" explain gravitational attraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222390/how-does-curved-space-explain-gravitational-attraction). The acceleration is caused by the curvature of spacetime. This curvature does also cause time to run more slowly as you approach a spherical mass, but the change in the rate taht time runs does not cause the acceleration.

Comment: John, how to differ in a better way between an acceleration caused by a force like circular motion in a particle generator and a free fall which is not an acceleration?

Comment: is it a duplicate of "How does "curved space" explain gravitational attraction?" ?