# Can I fly my spaceship within a black hole's ISCO and still escape?

Tags: black-holes

Regarding black holes: I recently learned that the Schwarzschild radius (where nothing can escape) is not the only interesting limit. There is an "Innermost stable circular orbit" (ISCO) which can be about 3 times as big. From what I've read online, if a point mass gets closer than ISCO then it will spiral into the black hole. But I'm wondering: if I have a spaceship with a strong energy source (e.g. antimatter propulsion) can it get closer than ISCO -- may be even near the Schwarzschild limit -- and still get away?

Comment: You may enjoy Rob's answers to this related question about ballistic (i.e., unpowered) trajectories around a Schwarzschild black hole: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772180/123208

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646073/123208

Comment: The answer is just above the event horizon and the reasoning is in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646073/a-space-ship-has-maximum-proper-acceleration-of-a-0-how-close-can-it-fall-fre?noredirect=1&lq=1