# What explains the descrepancy between Asaph Hall's equation for Mercury's precession and GR?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, orbital-motion, precession, modified-gravity

In regard to [What is the weight equation through general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47379/), the answer is:

$$F=ma=\frac{GMm}{r^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{c^2r}}}.$$

This [source](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node116.html) provides a different equation:
$$f \approx - \frac{G M_0}{r^2} - \frac{3 G M_0 h^2}{c^2 r^4}.$$

And these two results go in the same direction of increasing the acceleration over Newton's equations. I'm not concerned with reconciling the differences between those two equations.

But Asaph Hall found ([source](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s6-02/6-02.htm)):

> Hall noted that he could account for Mercury's precession if the law of gravity, instead of falling off as $\frac{1}{r^2}$, actually falls of as $\frac{1}{r^n}$ where the exponent $n$ is $2.00000016$.

This would result in reduced acceleration compared to Newton's equations, and hence goes in the opposite direction suggested by GR.

It is a curious thing that either an increasing or a decrease in the acceleration could explain the motions of Mercury.  Now, I know that Asaph Hall's finding was not found to be correct as a theory for gravity, and that GR has been.  But as far as I can tell, his math wasn't wrong for the specific case of Mercury.

What explains how both GR and Asaph could explain Mercury's motion?

Comment: ["With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk." John von Neumann](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/06/21/how-to-fit-an-elephant/)

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thanks for updating the question.  It's not so much that a different and wrong equation can fit the data, but rather that a wrong force could fit the data that I find interesting.

Comment: That is just tuning an arbitrary formula to fit with _one_ planet, disregarding the others.  This should be obvious from the remainder of the paragraph in the source!

Comment: Why do you believe that Asaph's formula would lead to a reduced acceleration for Mercury? This depends entirely what is being kept fixed!

Comment: @mmeent well, to my knowledge everything else was kept fixed.

Comment: @HardlyCurious You can’t keep everything fixed. In particular, because the mass of the sun is exactly determined through its gravitational interaction with the planets, a steeper decay of the gravitational potential would imply a higher mass of the sun to account for the motion of the planets further out.

Comment: @mmeent You are missing the point of the question I'm afraid.

Comment: @HardlyCurious I am suggesting that the question is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @mmeent what you are saying is that since asaph's equation doesn't solve for the motions of the entire solar system, that I shouldn't ask why it works for Mercury.

Comment: No that is not what I am saying. I am saying that if you keep the size and period of the earth's orbit fixed (i.e. empirical observable quantities) , Hall's ansatz will work in the same direction as the GR correction in terms of the size of the force. (Whether that helps explaining the direction of the periapsis precession is still a separate question.)

Answer (score 1):

Hall changed the proportionality for the force, but you need to know the constant of proportionality in order to say whether the gravitational force was stronger or weaker.

If the gravitational constant is fixed by (e.g.) requiring the Earth to have an orbital period of 1 year at 1 au, then having $n>2$ would require an increase in the constant of proportionality in the force equation.

If this constant of proportionality is then applied to an object at smaller orbital radii than the Earth then the gravitational force would be larger than the Newtonian value.

If we have a look at [Hall (1894)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1894AJ.....14...49H/abstract), where the original suggestion was made, you will see on p.50 that a new parameter is defined
$$ \mu = \mu' r^\Delta\ ,$$
where $\Delta = 0.00000016$ represents the departure of the force scaling from the inverse square law and $\mu$ is the gravitational constant for the Sun and Mercury.

In that case, the acceleration at the position of Mercury is given by
$$ a = \frac{\mu}{r^{2+\Delta}} = \frac{\mu'}{r^{2}}\ . $$

However, I don't think one cares what the strength of the gravitational field is. What matters in terms of whether and in what direction the precession is, is how the force varies with $r$. A general expression for the factor by which the apsidal angle$^1$ differs from $\pi$ is (see [here](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node45.html#e6.81))
$$ \psi = \pi\left( 3 + r \frac{F'(r)}{F(r)}\right)\ ,$$
which does not depend on the magnitude of $F(r)$.

$^1$ The angle through which the radius vector rotates between aphelion and perihelion - which would be $\pi$ for a Keplerian orbit.

Comment: So this is what mmeent seemed to be saying as well.  And I have a couple issues with it.  Firstly, do we know that this is what Hall did?  I didn't find anything stating so.  And second, Halls work was based of Bertrand's Theorem.  We can ignore the force in absolute terms because Bertrand's Theorem isn't about the masses involved, only the force relationship to distance.  I made another question more directly about Bertrand's Theorem in this case because I feel like that gets to the core a little better.

Comment: Here is the other question for reference. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702524/is-bertrands-theorem-consistent-with-gr?noredirect=1#comment1572346_702524