# How strong is gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

How strong is the gravity of general relativity?

How much radial force is required to keep a particle with mass $m$ at a certain distance $r$ from a black hole with mass $M$? We know that Newtonian gravity $$f=\frac{GmM}{r^2}$$ provides a good approximation of the force, $f$, for low energy cases. But what is the exact difference a) for a far-away observer, and b) within the reference frame of the particle?

Comment: Your question title is vague. The equation is known as [Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation), and what you are asking is whether or not the law is meaningful in close proximity to a black hole (i.e., for very large values of $M$ and very small values of $r$.) Your question might attract more interest if its title contained words like "universal gravitation" and "black hole."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the weight equation through general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47379/)

Comment: @Solomon Slow: I don't agree with your comment, but thank you for your edits of my question, that's OK. - Indeed, my question is a duplicata, the first answer of the linked question is answering my question! Perhaps my title is a bit more "popular" and a bit easier to find. I did not find the linked question by myself.